# Are luck streaks programmed into the game, or does RNG just make it feel that way?

Tags: pokemon-duel

I've noticed that there are times where it feels like I always spin just the right attack, and other times when I feel like I always spin the wrong thing.  In either case, these lucky/unlucky streaks seem to be clumped together.  Is it possible that lucky/unlucky streaks are programmed into the game, or does RNG just make it feel that way?

Comment: This is almost certainly confirmation bias; our brains are programmed to see and recognize patterns, even if none exists.

Comment: @Frank I'll have to start documenting every spin from now on, to see if that's the case.